# Elastic search aggregation buckets remain empty

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, elasticsearch-aggregation

Since updating to ES 6.4 my aggregations return empty buckets. This is what the aggregation look like:

```
"measurements": {
            "terms": {
                // This decides the number of buckets
                "size": 20,
                "field": "measurements.raw"
            }
        },
        "part_type": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 20,
                "field": "part_type.raw"
            }
        }
```

This used to work perfectly. The mapping for this parts are:

```
"parts": {
    "properties": {
       "measurements": {
           "type": "text",
           "fields": {
               "keyword": {
                   "type": "keyword",
                   "ignore_above": 256
                   }
                 }
               },
               "part_type": {
                   "type": "text",
                   "fields": {
                       "keyword": {
                           "type": "keyword",
                           "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                },
 },
```

Somehow the buckets remain empty Arrays and I can't seem to figure out why. There is now error in the query.

A sample data return from a query search is:

```
 {
            "_index": "certificates",
            "_type": "certificate",
            "_id": "56a74f7c5dee788d0c3bc86f",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "certificate_number": "A10288",
                "certificate_type": "3.1B",
                "norm": "",
                "material_quality": "904L",
                "manufacturer": "BLABLA",
                "bb_code": "xxx",
                "attached_file": {
                    "originalname": "",
                    "filename": ""
                },
                "parts": [
                    {
                        "measurements": "Ø73.02x5.16",
                        "charge_number": "442665",
                        "probe_number": "",
                        "part_type": "ELBOW",
                        "comment": "",
                        "factory_code": "",
                        "_id": "56a74f7c5dee788d0c3bc870",
                        "mcl_order_number": [
                            {
                                "number": "43.9.069"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "created_by": {
                    "user_name": "System import"
                },
                "__v": 0
            }
        }
```

I've tried to rewrite is according to the 6.4 docs to make it look like this:

```
aggregations = {
    "parts": {
        "terms": {"field": "parts"},
        "aggs": {
            "measurements": {
                "terms": {"field": "parts.measurements.raw"}
            },
            "part_type": {
                "terms": {"field": "parts.part_type.raw"}
            },
        }
    }
}
```

This returns the following:

```
"aggregations": {
    "parts": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": []
    }
}
```

Comment: What version were you previously on?

Comment: 2.3. I've tried to do this now: 

      "parts": {
            "terms": {"field": "parts"},
            "aggs": {
                "measurements": {
                    "terms": {"field": "parts.measurements.raw"}
                },
                "part_type": {
                    "terms": {"field": "parts.part_type.raw"}
                },
            }
        }
However the buckets remain empty.

Comment: I updated the question with some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade from 2.3 to 6.4 is quite a huge one, and a lot of changes happened. If you have some time at some point, I highly recommend the [Breaking Changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html) section of the Elastic documentation. It will give you at least the rough idea of the big changes. At least check out the major releases 5 and 6.

Now, I think with 5.0 there were changes to the mapping. Some restrictions, some changes to default behavior. I'd guess that in your case, you are using the dynamic mapping; meaning you didn't specify the mapping yourself?

If I read your mapping correct, then you want to refer to the fields `measurements.keyword` and `measurements.part_type.keyword` fields in the aggregation. The `raw` field is not specified and might refer to an old default in 2.x.

Here is the most likely cause: [5.0 mapping changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#breaking_50_mapping_changes)

Comment: Thanks Slomo, this did the trick: 
   aggregations = {
            "measurements": {
                "terms": {
                    // This decides the number of buckets
                    "size": 20,
                    "field": "parts.measurements.keyword",
                    "missing": "N/A"
                }
            },
            "part_type": {
                "terms": {
                    "size": 20,
                    "field": "parts.part_type.keyword",
                    "missing": "N/A"
                }
            }
        }